# greatest number of balls in a box

Tags: geometry

**What is the greatest number of balls of radius $1/2$ that can be placed within a rectangular box of size $10*10*1$ ?**
I start considering that
(1) I can reduce the problem in 2D
(2) The centres of the balls must lie in a square $9*9$
Now I think I have to find a tassellation for this square in order to find the greatest number of centres I can place in it but I don't know how to proceed...

Comment: Of interest may be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rectangular pack would allow $10 \times 10=100$ balls.  Packing problems are hard.  [Packomania](http://www.packomania.com/) shows how to pack $106$ balls of radius greater than $0.05$ in a unit square.

Comment: How can I prove 106 is the best? It can't be so hard, it's an old IMO longlist problem

Comment: Many of the configurations on packomania are not proven to be the best.  $106$ is not listed in boldface, so the site does not consider it proven.  Many of them are just the result of a lot of trying different starting patterns, then "shaking" the circles trying to improve the radius.  That is why the problems are hard.  There might be a better configuration out there that we have not found yet.

Comment: 105 is not difficult to find - alternate rows with 10 balls and rows with 9 balls. This occupies $1+5\sqrt 3$ from the height. The remaining place of width $0.34$  is encouraging ... the packing from Packomania is better :)